# Running Windows 7 VM on XP machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I'm fairly certain that this is not possible, but just wanted to ask the really smart people to be sure.

My company wants to run a Windows 7 VM (using any virtual machine software) on an desktop running XP.  If this is possible, which VM software should they use?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can use Microsoft Virtual PC or free VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the VM software does emulate a complete PC, it is possible to run later versions of Windows on earlier version. Pretty much any decent VM software will allow you to do this.

Comment: You would think so, but I've tried VirtualPC and VirtualBox and both seem to start up, but BSOD.

Comment: Although, I was trying to create the VM from VHD files instead of just installing from scratch...so maybe I'll give that a try next.

Comment: Obviously it's hard to say what's going wrong but I have run Win7 in a VM on XP using VirtualBox and it worked. However I did put a fresh install into the VM, so that might be the one difference that actually gets things to work. Windows can get a bit funny if its ideas of what the hardware looks like and the "real fake" hardware differ too much. Like specifying the wrong type of disk controller or controller mode.

Comment: If I remember, MS said, cant do 64 virtual on 32bit system?